# Basic HTML file showing blank page

Tags: html

I just started learning html from Bindner's book (A Student's Guide to the Study, Practice, and Tools of Modern Mathematics), which has a chapter on it.

I wrote the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My Page <\title>
<\head>
<body>
<p> Hello everyone!   <\p>
<\body>
<\html>
```

in notepad++ and saved it as  `my site.html`. But when I opened it in browser, a blank page shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use an HTML validator.

Comment: Use a forward slash `/` instead of a backward slash `\`.
Also consider a HTML validator as @Xufox suggested - you can find one here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 2):

not `\` but `/` in close tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Hello everyone!   </p>
</body>
</html>
```